# What do manufactures put into coir (coconut fibre) "soil"

Tags: soil

I've used coir soil for my potted plants to make the soil a little less compressed. I've read the declaration and is says that it contains max 5% of coconut fibres.

What could be the other 95%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coir pith. See [What is Coir pith? Or “Coco-Peat”?](http://www.coirtrade.com/whatiscoir.html)

Answer (score 1):

They may just mean that only 5% is actual coconut fibre, and the rest is coconut husk of different grinds, some fine, some medium, some large. Coconut husk is different from coconut fibre - this latter is usually used to make doormats, mattress fillings, brooms and brushes. If it contains anything else (loam, peat, perlite and so on) that should be listed as well.